# Windows 8.1, Cannot relocate Users directory without windows failing to login properly

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, windows-registry, symbolic-link, users

I'm trying to relocate my C:\Users\Me folder on my SSD to F:\Users\Me which resides on my HDD.

So far I've tried two approaches.

**Registry**

Modifying the following registry keys in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"

"Default" = F:\Users\Me
"Profiles" = F:\Users
"ProgramData" = %SystemDrive%\ProgramData
"Public" = F:\Users\Public

Then finding the S-1-5-**** key that represents my profile and modifying

"ProfileImagePath" = F:\Users\Me

**Symlink**

Booting to windows 8.1 install USB and entering repair mode with command prompt.

At command prompt I renamed my C:\Users\Me folder to C:\Users\MeBak and ran "mklink \J C:\Users\Me F:\Users\Me" to create the junction (I also used \D with the same results)

Both of these methods result in Windows 8.1 loading up a temporary profile because it failed to find/load the correct one.

Any solutions that work for relocating the users folder to another drive?

Answer (score 0):

There are some guides to moving Windows default folders at

http://www.7tutorials.com/how-change-location-folders-such-documents-or-downloads and

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-move-windows-7-personal-folders-my-documents-another-drive.htm.

However, Windows has some locations hard-coded such as *hiberfil.sys*, so I would not be surprised if there were difficulties in moving *Users*, particularly since this also has the *Start Menu*, *AppData* and other folders needed at startup. You might be better served by keeping it on the SSD, in any case, since it's likely no more than 40 GB and speeds access to these frequently-updated files.